# POST Request with AFNetworkings AFHTTPSessionManager gets interpreted as GET on Heroku

Tags: heroku, afnetworking, afhttpclient

I am currently trying to POST to my heroku server.
Everything works fine locally but if i change my url for the AFHttpSessionmanager to the heroku App, my App wont work anymore cause the post requests gets interpreted as a GET Request on the Heroku-Side ..

This is how i do the Post-request :

```
NSString * postPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/freetextquestions/%ld/freetextanswers.json",(long)identifier];
        [[AskMeClient sharedClient] POST:postPath parameters: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.answerTextField.text forKey:@"text"]
                                      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
                                          NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
                                          [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                      } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                                          NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                          UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Ooops ..." message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                                          [alert show];

                                      }];
```

This is my Client :

```
@implementation AskMeClient

+(instancetype)sharedClient {
    static AskMeClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[AskMeClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AskMeAPIBaseURLString]];
        _sharedClient.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy defaultPolicy];
        _sharedClient.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        _sharedClient.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
        [_sharedClient.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}
@end
```

and this is what heroku says :

```
2014-02-24T00:32:35.246169+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/freetextquestions/3/freetextanswers host=topsecretapp.herokuapp.com request_id=b2876fdb-d4bf-403a-a05a-4539830f9f0e fwd="193.175.119.11" dyno=web.1 connect=9ms service=44ms status=404 bytes=351
```

I tried everything to eliminate this error but i cant get it to work ..
Does anybody has an idea what i am doing wrong ? Or is this a Heroku-Error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution for this.
If i use the subdomain provided by heroku it seems that the HTTP-Method gets lost in some way, maybe caused by some forwardings or redirects.
Now i am using a other domain that references on to my heroku-App and everything works fine.